# Query to accumulate status duration over time without overlap

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to create a bar graph over a given period of time that displays an accumulation of time for a given status using the results of a SQL Server query. The time for these status' cannot overlap (an entity cannot be two status' at once). The time period will not be over an 8-10 hour period. I have attached an image of sample data. In it you can see that the '123' entity went from status 3 to 7 for 2 minutes. The query below is close to what I need however, it does not take into account for the time affiliated with the different status' and is simply looking at the 'start' time and 'end' time for each status. Can someone point me in the right direction? Thanks!

```
SELECT state.status,
       min(state.timestamp) start_time,
       max(state.timestamp) end_time,
       datediff(second, min(state.timestamp),max(state.timestamp)) elapsed_sec,
       convert(varchar, max(state.timestamp) - min(state.timestamp), 108) accumulated_time
FROM state
WHERE state.entity = '123' AND CAST(timestamp AS DATE) = CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)
GROUP BY state.status;
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
with data as (
    select
        timestamp, entity, status,
        row_number() over (partition by entity order by timestamp, id) - 
            row_number() over (partition by entity, status order by timestamp, id) as grp
    from state
)
select entity, status, min(timestamp) as startTime, max(timestamp) as endTime
from data
group by entity, status, grp;
```